# translating text from English into Hindi return translatex000

Tags: python, dataframe, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, googletrans

I have a problem when i am using googletrans as a library with my data frame. its not showing a translated course-title in Hindi and im trying to translate from English to Hindi and currently its not doing what to expected, need some help its just return translatex0000.

```
import translate
from google_trans import Translator
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request as urllib2
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.classcentral.com/collection/top-free-online-courses"
driver.get(url)

#google translating languages
#translate = Translator()

try:
    while True:
        # wait until button is clickable
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
                expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-name='LOAD_MORE']"))
            ).click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
except Exception as e:
    pass

all_courses = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='catalog-grid__results')
courses = all_courses.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='[class="color-charcoal course-name"]')

df = pd.DataFrame([[course.text, course.get_attribute('href')] for course in courses],
                    columns=['Title (eng)', 'Link'])

df['Title (hin)'] = df['Title (eng)'].apply(lambda x: translate.Translator(x, dest='hi'))

print(df)
```

// scren-shot of the above code, translating hindi is x0000
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWOXw.png)